# How to test the throwing of errors in Racket's PLAI language

Tags: testing, racket, plai

I'm currently working in some racket programs, specifically in the PLAI's language of the [Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/%7Esk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/) Book, and there is a function called [`test`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plai/plai-scheme.html#%28form._%28%28lib._plai%2Fmain..rkt%29._test%29%29), i was wondering how to test the error throwing in racket? Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 11):

There is [`test/exn`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plai/plai-scheme.html#%28form._%28%28lib._plai/main..rkt%29._test/exn%29%29) that you can use to test error messages, for example:

```
(test/exn (error "foo") "foo")
```

but note that the docs say that it can test only exceptions that were explicitly raised by your code.  The idea is that your code should check for errors and raise them, otherwise you have a bug.

(For testing of "real" racket code, see [rackunit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/).

Comment: Although this answer is absolutely right for the question asked, some people (like me) might land here looking for the answer to the question's title (testing "lang racket" and not "lang plai").  The function you look for is `check-exn` within `rackunit`.  Here is [its documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._check-exn%29%29)